# Multiple item sync from sqlite to sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sqlite

I have built an android app which allows for users to save data to an offline sqlite database. Upon saving the data to the local sqlite database, the information is added to a listview. This data can then be pushed to a remote sql database hosted on xampp when a 'sync' button is clicked using AsyncTasks.

Currently I can only push one sqlite row at a time to the remote database - which is obviously not efficient. I would like to be able to have a method that would select all loans created today, and push these multiple rows to the online server.

What would be the best method to implement this?

Comment: It depends on the services that you have: if you have just a web service that allow to send one item (row) per time, then you can't do much

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even entirely sure what web service I'm using. I have used JSON to parse through to PHP, and from PHP to server. The php class I am using does only allow for one item to be created at a time, but I wonder could I create an array list of my sqlite rows and use a loop to continue calling that class until all the relevant rows have been parsed through?